# Error without initializing all stored properties return from initializer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift3.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1warm.png)

I'm converting swift 1.2 to swift 3.2 here init is showing error any suggesstion plese

```
var context:NSManagedObjectContext
var psc:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
var model:NSManagedObjectModel
var store:NSPersistentStore? = nil
var contextDict = [Int : NSManagedObjectContext]()
var results:NSBatchUpdateResult

init() {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    let modelURL =
    bundle.url(forResource: "maildough", withExtension:"momd")
    model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)!
    psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:model)
    context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
} ///getting error here
```

giving error as retrun from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: You missed `results` to initialize.

Comment: var results:NSBatchUpdateResult?
just try this.

Answer (score 0):

That how you need to do it for swift 3+

```
var errorHandler: (Error) -> Void = {_ in }

lazy var libraryDirectory: NSURL = {

    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()


lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "maildough", withExtension: "mom")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)!
}()


lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:
        self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = 
self.libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("maildough.sqlite")
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType:
            NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                           configurationName: nil,
                                           at: url,
                                           options: [
                                            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,

 NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
            ]
        )
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSLog("CoreData error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
        self.errorHandler(error)
    }
    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var mainManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return mainManagedObjectContext
}()
```